# MySQL - Assigning random string or names into real data table

Tags: mysql

Assuming I got the following result from the query below, is it possible to show an additional column at the end, at the same time assigning random names to each row of the column.

If its possible can the names be preassigned from the sql query? If the answer is no, are the names has to be selected from a separate user table?

```
mysql> select DISTINCT(ticketmaskid), departmenttitle, ticketstatustitle, totalreplies,
 SEC_TO_TIME(firstresponsetime) as firstresponsetime, dateline 
from (select DISTINCT(t1.ticketmaskid) as ticketmaskid, t1.departmenttitle, 
t1.ticketstatustitle, t1.totalreplies, t1.firstresponsetime, 
from_unixtime(t1.dateline) as dateline 
from swtickets t1 join swticketauditlogs t2 on t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
where t1.departmenttitle = 'Support' 
and from_unixtime(t1.dateline) between '2014-03-19 18:00:00' and '2014-03-19 23:59:59' 
and t1.firstresponsetime = '0') a 
order by dateline desc;
```

```
+---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| ticketmaskid  | departmenttitle          | ticketstatustitle | totalreplies | firstresponsetime | dateline            |
+---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
| PAF-798-78414 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 21:00:05 | 
| QKX-440-27460 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 20:23:25 |
| YSY-607-89300 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:30:01 |
| OBF-585-91079 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:18:11 |
| JFL-571-34597 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:14:36 |
| UNV-310-75924 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:11:02 |
| BQI-734-94486 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:08:26 |
| FWF-601-76792 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:33:56 | 
| HIL-530-30274 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:30:02 |
| GZR-272-44642 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:08:09 |
| MXY-801-80374 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:03:49 |
| UFX-287-74737 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:00:06 |
+---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.16 sec)

mysql>
```

i need to following output:

```
+---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+
| ticketmaskid  | departmenttitle          | ticketstatustitle | totalreplies | firstresponsetime | dateline            | Names      |
+---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------+
| PAF-798-78414 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 21:00:05 | John       |
| QKX-440-27460 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 20:23:25 | Michael    |
| YSY-607-89300 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:30:01 | Maria      |
| OBF-585-91079 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:18:11 | Jayme      |
| JFL-571-34597 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:14:36 | John       |
| UNV-310-75924 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:11:02 | Michael    |
| BQI-734-94486 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 19:08:26 | Maria      |
| FWF-601-76792 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:33:56 | Jayme      | 
| HIL-530-30274 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:30:02 | John       |
| GZR-272-44642 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:08:09 | Michael    |
| MXY-801-80374 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:03:49 | Maria      |
| UFX-287-74737 | Support                  | Open              |            0 | 00:00:00          | 2014-03-19 18:00:06 | Jayme      |
+---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+---------------------+-------------
12 rows in set (0.16 sec)
```

Comment: Can we assume you have a table of names with a primary_key of sequential integers? Are you expecting repeatable results - i.e., everytime you run it ticketmasterid=PAF-798-78414 will always be the same name or can the name differ?

Comment: a table of names with a primary_key of sequential integer. yes

Comment: i just want auto assigning tickets for available users

Comment: and yes repeatable results if possible.

Comment: what if i don't wish for repeatable results?

Answer (score 0):

If you want repeatable results then you need to store the values. You should either add a column to your swtickets table and run an update or create a new table with the ticketmaskid and the new column.

In the case of the latter, here is a code example which assumes you create a new table (ticket_person) with two columns (ticketmaskid & userid).

You can populate it this way:

```
INSERT INTO ticket_person (ticketmaskid,userid)
SELECT swtickets.ticketmaskid
     , FLOOR(lowvalue.minID + RAND()*(highvalue.maxID - lowvalue.minID))
FROM swtickets
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS minID FROM usertable) as lowvalue
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxID FROM usertable) as highvalue
LEFT JOIN ticket_person
  ON swtickets.ticketmaskid = ticket_person.ticketmaskid
WHERE ticket_person.ticketmaskid IS NULL;
```

When that is populated, you can get your values via a JOIN

```
SELECT swtickets.ticketmaskid
  , COALESCE(usertable.name,CONCAT('Unknown userID:',ticket_person.userid),'Not Assigned')
FROM swtickets
LEFT JOIN ticket_person
  ON ticket_person.ticketmaskid = swtickets.ticketmaskid
LEFT JOIN usertable
  ON usertable.id = ticket_person.userid;
```

---

For non-repeatable results, try this (which I modified you query - I did not understand how you were trying to use DISTINCT and the purpose of the inner query). If you don't want the CROSS JOIN's, hardcode the minimum and maximum values within the FLOOR function)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ticketmaskid, t1.departmenttitle, t1.ticketstatustitle
              , t1.totalreplies ,SEC_TO_TIME(firstresponsetime) as firstresponsetime
              , from_unixtime(t1.dateline) as dateline
              , (SELECT name 
                 FROM usertable 
                 WHERE usertable.id = FLOOR(lowvalue.minID + RAND()*(highvalue.maxID - lowvalue.minID))) as `name`
FROM swtickets t1 
JOIN swticketauditlogs t2 
  ON t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) AS minID FROM usertable) as lowvalue
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxID FROM usertable) as highvalue
WHERE t1.departmenttitle = 'Support' 
  AND from_unixtime(t1.dateline) BETWEEN '2014-03-19 18:00:00' AND '2014-03-19 23:59:59' 
  AND t1.firstresponsetime = '0' 
ORDER BY dateline DESC;
```

Comment: what if i don't wish to have a repeatable results. can you do the query as well

Comment: it came back ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: the issue is this. (SELECT name FROM usertable WHERE usertable.id = FLOOR(lowvalue.minID + RAND()*(highvalue.maxID - lowvalue.minID))) as `name

Comment: I don't understand how more than 1 value could be returned. **usertable.id** is supposed to be the primary key ~ hence the question from above `Can we assume you have a table of names with a primary_key of sequential integers`